# How to find an element by text in tags?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I use Python with Selenium to create simple web bot. I am struggling with searching clickable element on appearing rectangle. I want to localise it by "Given Text".

The code on website looks like this:

```
    <h5 class="some_class">Given Text</h5>
```

EDIT:

I couldn't find it by xpath, so I'm trying to read class name by method `get_attribute("class")` and from this - search for element - `find_element_by_class().` This is what I get `styles__StyledTitle-xvi3rp-0 BannerContentstyles__THBTitle-sc-1blzazq-1 Bjyxf`

The code:

```
        class_name = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'connected - Watches')]").get_attribute("class")

        browser.implicitly_wait(1)
        print(class_name)
        element = browser.find_element_by_class_name(str(class_name))

        ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()
```

Gives an exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

I care for not writing class name directly in script.

Comment: The xpath looks fine. What's the error?

Comment: I get list of elements:

        <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement 
        (session="34520ad39713fe2522078e4255d2cb6e", element="c3ab9ecb-6022- 
        47b0-acaa-fefb9a73cf84")>

When only one element is on website

Comment: array[0].click() causes an error

Comment: show url for this page - and then we can test it.

Comment: `find_element_...` can't give you list but only one element and you should do `array.click()`. Using `find_elements_...` with `s` in word `elements` you could get list.

Comment: OK - so are you using find_elements_by_xpath? - note the s in elements as this returns a list...  If you're using find_elements and getting a list it's because your xpath matches more than one object.in which case, what is your objective?  (you're question is you want to find it, and you found it) :-)

Comment: this `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="34520ad39713fe2522078e4255d2cb6e", element="c3ab9ecb-6022- 47b0-acaa-fefb9a73cf84")>` is NOT a list but one element. List would have `[  ]`

Comment: zalando-lounge.pl/event Method click() fails here. I want to enter to the event.

Comment: There's a country check on the event so i can't get to that page.  I think, quite simply, change  `browser.find_element_by_xpath`  to `browser.find_elements_by_xpath`   - then it will return an array then you will get past your current wall

Comment: will you have a go and let us know?  - if that doesn't work,  please share more code, share more of unchanged html, outline what you're trying to do and any error that occurs. These are all things we need to provide a real answer and not just guesses :-)

Comment: @RichEdwards okay. Finding element(s) by xpath works well.

Comment: I have done some research and I'm sure my problem comes from not interactable element. Now my biggest issue is getting class name from text. Here is code:

    `array = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Jack & Jones')]")`
    `name = array.get_attribute("class")`
    `print(name)`

    `button = browser.find_element_by_class_name("campaignOverlay___info- 
    header___15qrg")`
    `browser.implicitly_wait(1)`
    `print(button)`
    `ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()`

Comment: @kjtn99 - I think your question has changed a bit.  You initially asked about identifying objects, then in the comments said the click on the array item didn't work (for which you didn't have an array/list) you didn't share there was an error and now you think it's sync based.  Can you please update your question with the problem you're facing, more code, and any research you've done into it? - that will bring everyone back on the same page without reading a discussion :-)

Comment: @RichEdwards sorry for this but I'm a bit confused. I have edited question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to find out the name of the class, it's like this:

```
class_name = browser.find_element_by_xpath("some XPath").getAttribute("class")
```

Comment: I get something like this `styles__StyledTitle-xvi3rp-0 BannerContentstyles__THBTitle-sc-1blzazq-1 Bjyxf`. Is it correct? How can I find element by this? Because there are spaces inside

Comment: This is the text of the element, if you want the text in a specific container, you need to find the specific element which contains the text.

Comment: In other words, I just want to get class name: „some class” from „Given Text”

Comment: That would be this:
   class_name = browser.find_element_by_xpath("XPath to your 
    class").get_attribute("class")

Answer (score 0):

If you know the "Given Text", you can get the element with following code: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h5[contains(text(), 'Given Text')]")`. `.get_attribute("class")` can only come after an element (except there is just one).
So to get `some_class` use this: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h5[contains(text(), 'Given Text')]").get_attribute("class")`.